# Best black opening move for E4

Tags: sicilian-defense, online-chess, defense, 1.e4

Can some one tell me which is the best opening move when white plays e4, read somewhere, to counter e4 **Sicilian Defence** is one of the best?

Comment: There is no best.  The Sicilian and King's Indian are my favorites.

Comment: The best can be defined in different ways. But you can expand your question, e.g. explain what type of positions you want to achieve, then it will be more simple to narrow down the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is **unanswerable**, please consider rephrasing it.

The reason for me saying this is that every opening that has `=` evaluation in `ECO` is **good response** to `1.e4`. You could look for statistics on openings but it is **useless**-in my opinion statistics are stupid since they reveal to you nothing about the game. It is just a result of mathematical division-you can only use them to see which defense to `1.e4` **is the easiest to play with** for **most of the people**.

Compare the *French defense* and *Sicilian defense*:

Currently *Sicilian defense* "scores better" than *French defense* according to statistics, but that conclusion is "valid" if you sum up the efficiency of all the variations in both openings.

If you **remove** the dubious ***Rubinstein variation*** of the *French defense* from the calculation than **it scores nearly as good** as the **entire** *Sicilian defense*.

My point is that you have **many good** opening moves against `1.e4`, you just have to pick one you like.

Browse through openings against `1.e4`and pick one that **suites your style**.

This depends entirely up to you-if you like slow games **with small amount of variations to learn** then pick some semi-open defense ( *Caro-Kan*, *French-defense* and so on ) or if you have time to learn and wish open battle riddled with sharp tactical play then pick *Sicilian defense* or *Modern defense* or whatever.

Remember: **Each opening that is evaluated as valid**, meaning it gives **equal chances to both of you for winning** is a good candidate.

**You need to choose one that suits your style and just go with it.**

If you have further question leave a comment.

Best regards.

Comment: the one thing that I didn't understand.. It labeled evaluated by statistically decision.. Hope there some formula to approved that.. thanks.

Comment: @AhmadAzwarAnas: I did not understand your comment fully, but if you improve your English a bit, I could help you with an advice. Thank you for your compliment. Best regards.

Comment: as I learnt till now, good decision to move on chess based on statistic value.. I just hope someone can make  some formula instead of statistic value only.. sorry about my English.. I just too interested with your answer..